# Margin in dropdown list of Bootstrap Selectpicker

Tags: css, bootstrap-selectpicker

Too much time I have tried to trace the design, just for cleanup the space (margin) in bootstrap select picker dropdown list, but still not worked.

this is my css code

```
.bootstrap-select.btn-group .dropdown-menu li a span.text {
    min-width: 100%; margin: 0; padding:0; 
}
.bootstrap-select.btn-group .dropdown-menu li a span.text>small {
    margin: 0; padding:0; 
}
```

preview in the browser (chrome) and inspection

[image: Dropdown list]

[image: Inspection in chrome Browser]

Is there anyone know, which css code should be fixed..?
Thanks

Comment: Your CSS rules are probably being overridden by Bootstrap's. Post a [mcve] in your question so that we can see.

Comment: Thx for reply, I created the css and did not change the original from bootstrap, and all the css code related to the preview above is just that, nothing else. how should I remove the orange distance?

Comment: Again, we need a [mcve] which in this case would include the HTML and your CSS to recreate the issue you're seeing

Comment: you mean use jsfiddle..?

Comment: well, i've found the solution, 
`.bootstrap-select.btn-group.show-tick .dropdown-menu li a span.text {
  margin-right: 0px;
}`